# How to play background audio using AVFoundation for iPhone/iPoad Touch with iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, ipod-touch, avfoundation

I think that it's clear from the title...

**The Problem:**
I already have some objective-c code that uses AVFoundation and its AVAudioPlayer to play some sounds in my iPhone apps, it takes a path for a folder in the documents and plays all the files in it one after the other using an AVAudioPlayer object (I implemented AVAudionPlayerDelegate so I can give the player the next file when the current one is done)...

**The Question:**
Now how can I keep these sounds playing when my app is in the background cause I upgraded my devices to iOS 4.1 and also my iOS SDK and Xcode...

**What I did:**
I added the "UIBackgroundModes" to my info.plist file and put "audio" in it and I set the category for the sharedInstance in AVAudionSeession to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback and setActive to YES and no errors happened there but still when I press the home button, the music stops!

What else should I do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem,and solved this way: I added UIBackgroundModes and put audio there. Then in my AudioPlayer class (class where i play my audio) in "init" method i've put this code:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
```

**NOTE**: In simulator this will not work! You need real device.